# Browser does not show Small Letter image name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How I can allow to load Small Letter image name
Getting 404 error for ebay.jpg

But

Ebay.jpg load with no issue
Existing image name in folder is Ebay.jpg

So I want to view ebay.jpg in browser using htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
<FilesMatch \.(?i:jpg)$>
```

You can multiple mime type entries in the case-insensitive list as below:

```
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css)$">
```

In order to get more information on its usage, you can refer the following link to htaccess documentation

[.htaccess Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html)

Comment: can we call same file name with different name Such as  Ebay.jpg, ebay.jpg
in browser

Comment: Yes. For that create multiple copies of the file, its as simple as that